# Engineering economy total cost

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

A firm operators in a perfectly competitive market whose total cost varies as
$TC = X^3 - 3X^2 -10X + 2$, and the price of the product they manufacture is given by 
$P = 130 - 2X$, where $X$ is number of units of output.

1. what optimum number of units should be produced in order to maximize profits?
2. what is the profit if the optimum number of units is produced?
3. what is the number of units that should be produced and sold each month in order to maximize profit?
4. show that your answer to Part 1 a maximizes profit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Why is 3 different than 1?  We don't have a time span in 1 or 2.  You should look at the marginal cost of the last unit and compare with the price, so you want $TC(X)-TC(X-1)=P(X)$, so you just break even on the last unit (or maybe one less than that).  Then the profit is $XP(X)-TC(X)$ as the first is income and the second it cost.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the point where marginal price = marginal revenue.  In other words take the first derivative or total cost and price and set them equal to each other.